# Session options not working?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to use the `session_get_cookie_params` function ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)) in PHP (running on a web server). However, for some reason, it's still using the default values.

My code:

```
ini_set('session.name', 'SESSION');
session_set_cookie_params((60*60*2), "/", "hexrblx.com", TRUE);
session_start();
```

([Session configuration values](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php))

Comment: And your PHP version is ?

Comment: Oh, that was dumb. 5.6.9, it was added in 7.0.0. Thanks. @frz3993

Comment: Take a look at `session_set_cookie_params()`.

Comment: @frz3993 Still not working; updated the question.

Comment: It is said in the first comment on the documentation page that the lifetime is not working as you might think it does.

Comment: It's not setting the cookie at all @AntoineB